# Scripting a pause in steam

Tags: team-fortress-2, dota-2, source-engine

Is there a way to make a steamscript wait/hold for a certain time before the next action/command gets executed?

I found the `wait` command and apparently it was used in TF2 scripts.

I tried using it in DotA2 but the console tells me that it does not know the command.

Is there any way around this/archiving the same outcome?

Comment: out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @char1es i wanted to control the flow of execution since some commands are faster then others even if they were started first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait` is not a `steam` command, but rather a `source engine` console command.

DOTA2 list of commands can be found here:

http://dota2.gamepedia.com/List_of_Console_Commands

Of interest is the server command "sv_allow_wait_command" which implies that "wait" can be disabled by the server.

Comment: i will edit my tags then. so wait is controlled by the server which means it will need sv_cheats = 1. this answer does not yet help me to get it working

Comment: `sv_allow_wait_command` must be enabled (i.e. set to 1) on the server to allow clients to use wait commands in their scripts.
There's no way around this - use of the `wait` command is often considered cheating.